# How to put values on each bar in a bar chart

Tags: jasper-reports, bar-chart

I am working with Jaspersoft studio 2015 and I have a stacked bar chart, I want to show the total value of each of bar on top of the bar. Can you shed some light on how this is done please?

Answer (score 2):

Basically setting Background Alpha %, Foreground Alpha %, Show Label=true, show Tick label=True and selecting a range should do the trick!

The config looks something like this:
[image: Configuartion in the Jasper reports]

And the Graph shown is

[image: Graph Example]
IF you further want to manipulate these values, just go to the Label expression and use java function to manuplate!

Example:-
If you want to display 50.00% instead of 50 use label expression like:
f{value}.toString().concat("%")

Cheers!!